# Remove the ArrayOfObjects based on ID within it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my array of objects named as **mycart[]**
:

> [{"id":"6","quantity":"20","price":1500,"title":"casual blue strip"},
>   {"id":"10","quantity":"2","price":1500,"title":"casual blue
>   round neck"},{"id":"5","quantity":20,"price":150,"title":"casual brown
>   shoes"},{"id":"8","quantity":5,"price":1500,"title":"casual blue
>   strip"},{"id":"19","quantity":7,"price":1190,"title":"kids sports
>   wear"},{"id":"18","quantity":5,"price":1290,"title":"Lotto sports"}]

Now if i want to remove complete object based on it's id.For ex:

if my id is 10, then i want to remove

> {"id":"10","quantity":"2","price":1500,"title":"casual blue round neck"}

output should be:

> [{"id":"6","quantity":"20","price":1500,"title":"casual blue strip"}, {"id":"5","quantity":20,"price":150,"title":"casual brown shoes"},{"id":"8","quantity":5,"price":1500,"title":"casual blue strip"},{"id":"19","quantity":7,"price":1190,"title":"kids sports wear"},{"id":"18","quantity":5,"price":1290,"title":"Lotto sports"}]

Now,i am struck at just matching the object-id:

```
var p ='10';
    for(var x=0; x < mycart.length; x++){
        if(mycart[x].id == p){
        found = true;
        break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need to add:

```
mycart.splice(x, 1);
```

See the snippet below::

```js
    var mycart = [{"id":"6","quantity":"20","price":1500,"title":"casual blue strip"},
          {"id":"10","quantity":"2","price":1500,"title":"casual blue round neck"},
          {"id":"5","quantity":20,"price":150,"title":"casual brown shoes"},
          {"id":"8","quantity":5,"price":1500,"title":"casual blue strip"},
          {"id":"19","quantity":7,"price":1190,"title":"kids sports wear"},
          {"id":"18","quantity":5,"price":1290,"title":"Lotto sports"}];


    var p ='10';
    for(var x=0; x < mycart.length; x++){
      if(mycart[x].id == p){
      found = true;
      break;
       }
 }

    mycart.splice(x, 1);

      document.write(JSON.stringify(mycart));
```

Comment: thank you @agershun,  silly thou!!it is what i expected it to happen. Was helpful